# How to align bootstrap dropdown and others together in a grid layout?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create filters whose layout should match something like below screenshot.
[image]

So far I am able to achieve something like the given below screenshot.
[image]

Problem is I am unable to evenly distribute items in terms of space as shown in 1st screenshot. Also is it good way to create this kind of layout using table?

Please help me in understanding and creating this layout.

Below is my code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 20px;">
        <div class="panel-title pull-left text-label-emphasize" style="margin-top: -8px;"><b>Filter</b></div>
        <div class="panel-title pull-right text-label" style="margin-top: -8px;">Reset</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <div class="dropdown" ng-show="!loadinga" style="text-align: left;" width="100%">
                        <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle" type="button" style="text-align: left; background-color: #fff; border-color: #C3C3C3; " ng-disabled="loading">
                            {{dropDownTitle}}
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-menu nav" role="menu">
                            <li ng-repeat="agent in agentListData">
                                <a role="menuitem" href="#" ng-click="">{{agent}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="1">
                    <div class="dropdown" ng-show="!loadinga" style="text-align: left;" width="100%">
                        <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle" type="button" style="text-align: left; background-color: #fff; border-color: #C3C3C3; " ng-disabled="loading">
                            {{dropDownAllTaskStatusTitle}}
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-menu nav" role="menu">
                            <li ng-repeat="task in taskStatusListData">
                                <a role="menuitem" href="#" ng-click="">{{task.title}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="1">
                    <div ng-show="!loadinga">
                        <input id="autoComplete" type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="task.name for task in taskList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:20" class="form-control" typeahead-on-select='' placeholder="Search Tasks here" typeahead-focus-first="true" ng-disabled="loading" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" style="padding-right: 200px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="isAdvancedFilterAvailable" style="padding:2px">
                <td colspan="4">
                    <hr/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="isAdvancedFilterAvailable" class="fadein fadeout">
                <td align="left" colspan="1">
                    <div style="margin-right: 5px;margin-left: 5px; margin-top:2px" ng-show="!loadinga">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-click="checkboxClicked(isChecked)" ng-disabled="loading" />
                        <label for="excludeMinutesStep">Exclude tasks running &lt; </label>
                        <input id="excludeMinutesStep" type="number" min="0" max="10" ng-disabled="!isChecked || loading" ng-model="excludeValue" ng-change="" size="2" style="width:40px" /> <b>minutes</b>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="1">
                    <div style="margin-right: 5px; margin-top:2px" ng-show="!loadinga">
                        <input id="datalabels" type="checkbox" ng-model="isLabelShowChecked" ng-click="" ng-disabled="loading" />
                        <label for="datalabels">Show Labels</label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" style="padding-right: 200px"></td>
                <td colspan="1" style="padding-right: 200px"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="padding:2px">
                <td colspan="4">
                    <hr/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <a ng-show="!isAdvancedFilterAvailable" ng-click="isAdvancedFilterAvailable=true">Show Advanced Filters</a>
                    <a ng-show="isAdvancedFilterAvailable" ng-click="isAdvancedFilterAvailable=false">Hide Advanced Filters</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.text-label {
    color: #aab2bd;
    font: 8pt;
}
.text-label-emphasize {
    color: #575F64;
}
```

Comment: I would like to say using `div` inside `td` is not a good approach. If you are using bootstrap, why don't use its grid system to build your layout? [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: @RLam: In grid layout how can I have spacing between 2  elements?

Comment: a class like col-offset-md-*  you may find it in the doc s well

Comment: I'm writing this for you now give me a second. Ill add some documentation to it to help also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap have tons of weeks dedicated to making all the "style elements" into classes, use them. As blunt as that is, read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/) when stuck it truly can help you.

Apart from that lets get stuck into your issue.
If you really need to use `table` in your panel then, the [best practice](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables) is to place it below or before `.panel-body` but since we want to maintain responsive mobile first technology for all our future projects, try to avoid it unless you actually want a table for data. [Nested columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) are the best practice to maintain this.

An example of how to nest any column is to use `.row` followed by the column size you wish to nest, example below.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

This would create good breakpoints and allow you to maintain a good UI/UX for your application.

Its important to understand bootstrap doesn't provide all the answers but it's a good style framework to expand from, so we make overriding css changes.

> I added a few css overrides to make the borders square, and tried to
>   maintain your angular.js (you may need to review that)

Completed code with preview hosted on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/BDzD0V3OsH)

For the style checkboxes, take a look at [Awesome Bootstrap Checkboxes](https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox), full documentation by them is available on their github.

**Edit** (Full width dropdown menu) --
To have the dropdown menu match the width of the button add the following css code to your overriding stylesheet.

```
.open>.dropdown-menu {
      min-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. one more thing, when I click the drop down it's width and dropdown's title width does not match. Can you please help me get same width for dropdown title and actual dropdown?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You may also find this question/answer helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590929/setting-the-width-of-a-dropdown-list-in-bootstrap-3-0

Comment: I again need your help on similar lines. Please take a look at [this continuing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454465/need-help-in-aligning-items-together-in-bootstrap-grid-layout). At present I am not looking at mobile friendly site so removed `col-sm` & `col-xs`.