# Options in select box not responsive

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

The options in my select field are not responsive .

[image]

I use a php loop to display options and I think the problem comes from there :

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sélectionner un article</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                 <select class="form-control m-b-sm" name="a_idarticle" id="a_idarticle">
                      <?php
                         foreach ($allarticles as $aa) {
                             echo '<option value="'.$aa['id_article'].'">'.$aa['id_article'].'--'.$aa['titre'].'</option>';
                         }
                      ?>
                </select>
         </div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know a solution ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried with other column width but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think this is purely based on how many options you have. Looking at the scrolling bar, it seems you have a lot of options. Consider using an ajax loader ( https://select2.github.io/examples.html )

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the link and yes, you are right there are many options, but I think the problem is that bootstrap can not add style to the option tag because it is in a php tag. There is a way to force style in php ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be the use of ellipsis

Try to change the CSS property for select and option attr in your form:

**CSS:**

```
#a_idarticle, #a_idarticle option {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

References:
[Ellipsis for overflow text in dropdown boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes)

**Edit to add another solution:**
In addition, you could use a button to wrap the dropdown, like in this post: [Setting the width of a dropdown list in Bootstrap 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590929/setting-the-width-of-a-dropdown-list-in-bootstrap-3-0)

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting answer , but it does not solve the problem ...
I'll test with a dropdown button