# Overriding bootstrap data-toggle="dropdown" width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boostrap `data-toggle="dropdown"` have natively a width of `991px`. I need to fix this with for maximum `767px`.

My code is:

```
 <a href="/Samohyl/peugeot" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Peugeot</a>
```

Comment: if you know css is possibile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the width of a dropdown list in Bootstrap 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590929/setting-the-width-of-a-dropdown-list-in-bootstrap-3-0)

Comment: nope problem is that boostrap add by js data-toggle="dropdown" from 991px width but i need it to add data-toggle="dropdown" to element only from 767px and less

Answer (score 0):

try below option.

```
<style type="text/css">
.cls .dropdown-toggle{
width:yourwidth px;
}
</style>
<div class="cls">
<a href="/Samohyl/peugeot" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Peugeot</a>
</div>
```

this way, only point to "cls" class sections and not others

refer to the below link

[Setting the width of a dropdown list in Bootstrap 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590929/setting-the-width-of-a-dropdown-list-in-bootstrap-3-0)